# How to change middle content with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know how to use ajax to pull data from a database. Using a MVC framework i would normally do a POST ajax request to my controller which would call a model and send back the details.

But i actually want to just pull through html from another file into the current file.

So for example i have a page like this:

```
<nav>

</nav>
<div id="leftNav">

</div>
<div class="content-body">

     <h1>This is the starting content body</h1>     

</div>
```

Now i have another file called blocks.php which has the following:

```
<h1>This is the second content-body</h1>
```

Using ajax how can i change the content-body with this blocks.php file?

Comment: `$('.content-body').html('response')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use jQuery, load api is good for that

```
$( ".content-body" ).load( "blocks.php", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

you can get more example from this url - http://api.jquery.com/load/

or post

```
$.post('blocks.php' , { key : value } , function(data){
  $('.content-body').html(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks , so easy! I just havent needed to do this before :)

Answer (score 0):

Do a simple ajax call

```
$.ajax({ url:"blocks.php",dataType:'html',success:function(data) {
  $( ".content-body" ).html(data)
}});
```